# Why is it necessary to add redundant trait bounds even though my trait uses those same traits as bounds?

Tags: rust, traits

I have been trying to code a trait which requires a type to implement `Add` (and further down the line other operations for vector spaces) with itself as well as among its references. The following is a small example, illustrating the problem I ran into:

```
use std::ops::Add;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyVec<T>(Vec<T>);

impl<'a, 'b, T: Copy + Add> Add<&'a MyVec<T>> for &'b MyVec<T> {
    type Output = MyVec<T::Output>;
    fn add(self, other: &'a MyVec<T>) -> Self::Output {
        /* ... */
    }
}
impl<'a, T: Copy + Add> Add<MyVec<T>> for &'a MyVec<T> {
    /* ... */
}
impl<'a, T: Copy + Add> Add<&'a MyVec<T>> for MyVec<T> {
    /* ... */
}
impl<T: Copy + Add> Add<MyVec<T>> for MyVec<T> {
    /* ... */
}

trait Addable: Add<Self, Output = Self>
where
    Self: Sized,
    for<'a> &'a Self: Add<Self, Output = Self>,
    for<'b> Self: Add<&'b Self, Output = Self>,
    for<'a, 'b> &'a Self: Add<&'b Self, Output = Self>,
{
}

impl<T: Copy + Add<Output = T>> Addable for MyVec<T> {}

fn add_stuff<'a, 'b, T: Addable>(x: &'a T, y: &'b T) -> T {
    x + y
}

fn main() {
    let v = MyVec(vec![1, 2, 3]);
    let w = MyVec(vec![2, 4, 6]);
    println!("{:?}", add_stuff(&v, &w));
}
```

- I use the `newtype` pattern to create an alias of `Vec` so I can implement a foreign trait (`Add`) on a foreign struct (`Vec`).
- I implement `Add` for `MyVec` and its references. The associated type `Output` is always the (unreferenced) `MyVec`. The latter three `impl`s are implemented in terms of the first.
- `Addable` is the central trait that I want to demo. Things that are addable should allow themselves and their references to be added with the result being `Self`. Particularly, in `add_stuff` I want the expression `x + y + x` to be valid where `x + y` gives a non-ref which can be added with `x` (which has not been moved out of, because it's a ref) to produce another non-ref.
- I don't get any complaints from the compiler regarding the implementation of the `Addable` trait on `MyVec`. Specifically, the compiler seems to recognize that the above `impl`s satisfy the bounds in the `where` clause.

However, I get the following compiler errors:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'a> &'a T: std::ops::Add<T>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:33:1
   |
33 | / fn add_stuff<'a, 'b, T: Addable>(x: &'a T, y: &'b T) -> T {
34 | |     x + y
35 | | }
   | |_^ no implementation for `&'a T + T`
   |
   = help: the trait `for<'a> std::ops::Add<T>` is not implemented for `&'a T`
   = help: consider adding a `where for<'a> &'a T: std::ops::Add<T>` bound
   = note: required by `Addable`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'a, 'b> &'a T: std::ops::Add<&'b T>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:33:1
   |
33 | / fn add_stuff<'a, 'b, T: Addable>(x: &'a T, y: &'b T) -> T {
34 | |     x + y
35 | | }
   | |_^ no implementation for `&'a T + &'b T`
   |
   = help: the trait `for<'a, 'b> std::ops::Add<&'b T>` is not implemented for `&'a T`
   = help: consider adding a `where for<'a, 'b> &'a T: std::ops::Add<&'b T>` bound
   = note: required by `Addable`
```

This can be fixed by amending the `add_stuff` function with a `where` clause as suggested by the compiler:

```
where
    for<'c, 'd> &'c T: Add<&'d T, Output = T>,
    for<'c> &'c T: Add<T, Output = T>,
```

I do not understand why this is necessary. I thought by specifying a bound in the definition of the trait I could rely on that bound being met for any type that implements that trait? Having to add these `where` clauses every time sort of defies the whole point of my `Addable` trait.

Googling brought up [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20671) which I don't understand fully but which might be related? That would suggest this is indeed a bug in Rust (which hasn't been fixed for a very long time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've hit a shortcoming of the Rust compiler as it currently is. [RFC 2089](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2089) proposed to make it work as you expect, and was accepted in December 2017.

However, as of today, the feature isn't implemented. The [tracking issue for the implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44491) hasn't seen much activity yet, so it appears implementation hasn't even started. It appears that some fundamental improvements to the compiler's trait bound handling are necessary before this particular feature can be efficiently implemented (search keyword: chalk).

Comment: Well, at least then my understanding is correct and I can always remove those redundant trait bounds once the RFC is fully implemented. It seems like a major flaw though, but at least the RFC has been accepted recently, so I'm hopeful it will gain some traction.

Comment: Chalk is not required for implied bounds. What is blocking now is mostly design work.

Comment: This is not just a shortcoming IMO. It makes Rust borderline-unusable even in very basic applications of generic arithmetic as pointed out in [this comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44491#issuecomment-931960916). Being forced to repeat the same complicated trait bounds for all operations everywhere is not feasible and especially frustrating since they are clearly redundant. It is really disappointing that since the acceptance of that RFC **6 years ago**, this is still an issue.