# Bounding a Trait by Requirements on associated Reference Type

Tags: rust, traits

I recently started learning rust and am exploring the type system.  I am wondering if there is a way to express the following trait:

> If a type `Foo` has the trait `RefAddable` then two references to `Foo` can be added together to produce a new (non-ref) `Foo`.

searching around a bit I came across "Higher-Rank Trait Bounds" and it initially seems that this works:

```
use std::ops::Add;

trait RefAddable
where
    for<'a> &'a Self: Add<Output = Self>,
{}
```

Indeed, I can only add `impl RefAddable for Foo {}` if I have also implemented `impl<'a> Add for &'a Foo`.  However, using `RefAddable` as a bound in a type seems not to have the effect I would expect.

In the following case I am presented with an error stating that it is missing the implementation of `&'a T + &'a T`

```
struct Bar<T>
where
    T: RefAddable,
{
    ...
}
```

This can be fixed by adding the bound from `RefAddable` to `Bar` to give

```
struct Bar<T>
where
    T: RefAddable,
    for<'a> &'a T: Add<Output = T>
{
    ...
}
```

So it seems that the bound of `RefAddable` isn't *really* expressing what I thought it was else the second bound wouldn't be needed as it would be implied by `RefAddable`.

So my questions are:

- Is there a way to express the `RefAddable` trait as described above?
- Why does the above implementation of `ReffAddable` not behave as I expected it would?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it necessary to add redundant trait bounds even though my trait uses those same traits as bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434716/why-is-it-necessary-to-add-redundant-trait-bounds-even-though-my-trait-uses-thos)

Comment: Have you been able to find a workaround for this while [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44491) is still open?